# Two buttons, it mix between the links

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Two buttons, it mix between the links

I have a page with two buttons, when I had the first button, it took me to the link, when I had the second button, the first stopped and the second took me to the second link, help!
PageOne.jave

```
package com.d.di;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PageOne extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abus);
        setContentView(R.layout.weoff);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.d.di;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abus);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weoff);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PageOne.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PageOne.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: PageOne will use layout of R.layout.weoff and not R.layout.abus. It replaces the layout not merge them.

Comment: What shall I replace it with?

Comment: You should pass some other info tag as Extras to identify which layout to load. or another way is to create a separate activity for pageTwo.

Comment: You need two have two Button instances in the PageOne class

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abus);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weoff);
```

It replaces the old reference to `R.id.weoff` so you will add the listener to `weoff`, two times which replaces the old listener and you set it with a listener which points to `PageOne.class`.

You should use two variables

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abus);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weoff);
```

and

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Since the two listeners point to the same Intent, you could create the listener only one time and put the same?

Comment: You created two variables? You added two redrict? Because right now the two buttons redrict to PageOne.

Comment: It works but it shows that the two button shows the second link only!

Comment: You should add the two buttons in only one layout.

Comment: It gave me an error -- button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abus);
  button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weoff);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Comment: What error? ofcourse you should adapt the examples.

Comment: I could paste the entire file in (Answer The Question) but it tells me after 8h! I can paste here but you know! The error is in [button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(] and here is the entire file